# Redshift SQL- How to groupby all columns but not create a separate row for each date. Select latest date instead

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like this

```
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| Product | Grade | Location | Date       | Value |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| A       | I     | GLOBAL   | 2020-02-11 | 100   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| A       | I     | GLOBAL   | 2020-03-22 | 200   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| B       | II    | ASIA     | 2020-02-11 | 300   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| B       | II    | ASIA     | 2020-04-22 | 300   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| C       | I     | GLOBAL   | 2020-04-04 | 100   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
```

I want to use groupby on all but select latest date instead of creating new row for each date.

Desired result:

```
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| Product | Grade | Location | Date       | Value |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| A       | I     | GLOBAL   | 2020-03-22 | 300   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| B       | II    | ASIA     | 2020-04-22 | 600   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| C       | I     | GLOBAL   | 2020-04-04 | 100   |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Could you please provide us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation with `group by`

```
select product, grade, location, max(date) as date,sum(value) as value
from tablename
group by product, grade, location
```